# How do I find my "computer description" in a Java application on Windows and/or Mac?

Tags: java, networking, dns, system

I have been struggling to find the "description" of the computer on which my Java application is running.

What I'm after is the name used for DNS when advertising my computer on the local network ("iMac Mattijs" in the screen shots below).

On Windows XP, this name can be found here: Control Panel -> System -> Computer Name -> Computer Description.

[image]

On Mac OS 10.6, this name can be found here: System Preferences -> Sharing -> Computer Name

[image]

The methods below don't deliver the name I'm looking for. Have a look at this code:

```
    System.out.println("COMPUTERNAME environment variable: " + System.getenv("COMPUTERNAME"));
    try { System.out.println("localhost name: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()); } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e1) {}

    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface thisInterface = interfaces.nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = thisInterface.getInetAddresses();

            System.out.println("* network interface: " + thisInterface.getDisplayName());
             while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                 InetAddress address = addresses.nextElement();
                 System.out.println(" - address: " + address.getCanonicalHostName());
             }
        }           
    } catch (SocketException e) {}
```

On Windows, this prints:

```
COMPUTERNAME environment variable: ARTTECH-51CA5F5
localhost name: arttech-51ca5f5
* network interface: MS TCP Loopback interface
 - address: localhost
* network interface: NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller - Packet Scheduler Miniport
* network interface: Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter - Packet Scheduler Miniport
 - address: arttech-51ca5f5.lan
* network interface: Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
```

On Mac, I get:

```
COMPUTERNAME environment variable: null
localhost name: imac-mattijs.lan 
* network interface: en1
 - address: imac-mattijs.lan
 - address: imac-mattijs.local
* network interface: lo0
 - address: localhost
 - address: fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1
 - address: localhost
```

But I am looking for the full String "iMac Mattijs".

Any clues would be very welcome!

Thanks,
Mattijs

Comment: "Description" should have nothing to do with DNS

Comment: Hi Matt, this "Computer description" (Windows)/"Computer name" (Mac OS) is what I see when I find my computer on the local network. So apparently this manually entered name is advertised by Bonjour/DNSSD, don't you think so?

Comment: This seems to be platform-specific, so you will have to retrieve the computer name you want differently for each platform you want to support in your Java application.

Comment: @Bernard: Judging by the lack of expertise on this topic I think you are right. For Mac, using the bonjour API might help, on Windows I don't have a clue apart from the MAST project mentioned by Andy below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS X stores the computer name in the System Configuration dynamic store. The standard interface to this is via the System Configuration framework. The commandline tool exercising this API is `scutil`:

```
$ scutil --get computerName
Hermes is awesome!
```

(I temporarily changed my computer name to something with spaces and punctuation so it would be readily distinguishable from the hostname, which in this case would be something like `hermes-is-awesome.local`.)

You can interface with this pretty easily using JNI:

```
class SCDynamicStore {
  public native String copyComputerName();
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("SCDynamicStore");
  }
}

class HostnameSC {
  public static void
  main(String[] args) {
    SCDynamicStore store = new SCDynamicStore();
    String computerName = store.copyComputerName();
    System.out.format("computer name: %s\n", computerName);
  }
}
```

Now `javac FILE.java` and then `javah SCDynamicStore`. This produces `SCDynamicStore.h`. Copy this to `SCDynamicStore.c` and edit it to read:

```
#include "SCDynamicStore.h"
#include <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_SCDynamicStore_copyComputerName(JNIEnv *env, jobject o)
{
  SCDynamicStoreRef store = NULL;
  CFStringRef computerName = NULL;
  CFStringEncoding UTF8 = kCFStringEncodingUTF8;
  CFIndex length;
  Boolean ok;
  jstring computerNameString = NULL;
  CFStringRef process = CFSTR("com.me.jni.SCDynamicStore");

  store = SCDynamicStoreCreate(NULL, process, NULL/*callout*/, NULL/*ctx*/);
  if (!store) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to get store\n");
    goto CantCreateStore;
  }

  computerName = SCDynamicStoreCopyComputerName(store, NULL);
  if (!computerName) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to copy computer name\n");
    goto CantCopyName;
  }

  length = CFStringGetLength(computerName);
  length = CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding(length, UTF8);
  {
    char utf8[length];
    if (!CFStringGetCString(computerName, utf8, sizeof(utf8), UTF8)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to convert to utf8\n");
      goto CantConvert;
    }
    computerNameString = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, utf8);
  }

CantConvert:
  CFRelease(computerName);
CantCopyName:
  CFRelease(store), store = NULL;
CantCreateStore:
  return computerNameString;
}
```

(You could simplify the code by using Obj-C toll-free bridging and taking advantage of `-[NSString UTF8String]`. It might be desirable to throw an exception instead of just returning `NULL` in some cases of error.)

You can then compile this using `clang -shared -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers/ -framework CoreFoundation -framework SystemConfiguration SCDynamicStore.c -o libSCDynamicStore.dylib`.

Now, provided `libSCDynamicStore.dylib` is along `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which it will be when it's in the current directory, you can run the application:

```
$ java HostnameSC
computer name: Hermes is awesome!
```

Comment: this is a great answer, it is very comprehensive, and it works!! Many thanks! For the sake of completeness, maybe you could change `java FILE.java` to `javac FILE.java` (assuming that is what you meant). Once more, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Here is what i found upon some experiments. The Computer Description is stored in the registry key

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters\srvcomment**

So, If we have any API which we can use to get the reg key values, we can find it out.

Also, Found the following link which gives a good class to query reg key values:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0630.html

And, Using the class WinRegistry given in the above site, I could successfully find out the Computer Description using the code:

```
String computerName = WinRegistry.readString(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\LanmanServer\\Parameters", "srvcomment");
```

Comment: This is a great answer, it works flawlessly! Although I marked Jeremy's answer for Mac as 'the' answer, this one fixes my problem for Windows, and you're a new user, so I awarded you the bounty! Thanks!

Comment: Please, please, please, _don't_ do this. This registry key is [technically documented](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787346(v=ws.10).aspx), but this is _not_ the supported way of querying this information. Use `NetServerGetInfo` with `SERVER_INFO_101` - this will be available via C/C++, Pinvoke, or JNI. In particular, some AV products lock the reg key, but the Net API continues to work.

Answer (score 3):

You should know that a single computer can have multiple DNS names.

Try this to obtain a name:

- Call `java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` to get all the network interfaces;
- For each `NetworkInterface` returned, call `java.net.NetworkInterface.getInetAddresses()` to get all the IP addresses of an interface;
- For each IP address returned, call `java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()` to get the associated hostname;
- Choose one of the hostnames.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately this route doesn't deliver the computer name I need as described in my question but the Full computer name.

Comment: @Mattijs Odd. The documentation on `InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()` indicates that it returns the fully-qualified hostname if at all possible. What does it return?

Comment: Hi Steve, I added screen shots to my original post to illustrate the issue. `InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()` returns arttech-51ca5f5, but I am looking for the name "iMac Mattijs"

Comment: @Mattijs Is only one name returned by the method I described? If not, is the name you're looking for amongst the other names?

Comment: @Steve: I added your suggestion to my original post, together with the results. Unfortunately none of the names returned represent the literal computer description, including capital letters etc..

Comment: @Mattijs In that case, it's likely that the computer name you're looking for is only available to the operating-system. and to Mac-specific programs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think its possible to get this without going native. If you can find a java library that gives you access to WMI then you can get it from the object Win32_OperatingSystem in the field Description.

Googling gives a few likely options;

http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/
Very simple (and free) if a little hacky. Seems to work by writing .vbs scripts to a temp dir and invoking them with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and cscript.exe.

https://com4j.dev.java.net/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/
Java COM bridge.

I think the Microsoft JVM has native bits included in it that may help too.

Comment: thanks for these pointers! I'll have a look and see if I can find a way through :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Get [com4j](https://com4j.dev.java.net/files/documents/1800/81644/com4j-20080107.zip) (direct download link)
   which is a Java library to make calls to
   COM.
2. Unzip and in the sample folder you
   will find a WMI
       sample.
3. Change the Main.java to the following and you should be set.

```
    
    package wmi;

    import com4j.Com4jObject; 
    import wmi.events.ISWbemSinkEvents; 

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Connecting to WMI repository");
            ISWbemLocator wbemLocator = ClassFactory.createSWbemLocator();
            ISWbemServices wbemServices = 
                    wbemLocator.connectServer(
                       "localhost","Root\\CIMv2","","","","",
                       0,null);

            System.out.println("connected");
            {
                System.out.println("Query Computer Description");
                ISWbemObjectSet result = wbemServices.execQuery(
                        "Select Description from Win32_OperatingSystem",
                          "WQL",48,null);
                for( Com4jObject obj : result ) {
                    ISWbemObject wo = obj.queryInterface(ISWbemObject.class);
                    System.out.println(wo.getObjectText_(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although this seems slightly more elaborate than querying the registry key directly, this is probably the official way to do this on Windows. And it's a great example! I wish I could award the bounty twice, or at least mark multiple answers as the accepted answer. I tested this and it works! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`InetAddress`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html).[`getHostName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName%28%29)?

```
System.out.println(
 "Name: " + java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() );
```

Edit: So the above answer is obviously not what you wanted. However... The [MAST](http://mast.ihmc.us/index.php) project does provide a method to retrieve the computer description. See `SysUtils`.[`getComputerDescription()`](http://mast.ihmc.us/docs/platAPI/us/ihmc/mast/platapi/SysUtils.html). This method is OS specific. The project homepage says that an OSX release is in the works.

Comment: indeed, looking at the API, it seems MAST found a way to do what I need on Windows. Unfortunately their source doesn't seem to be open.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the project is closed. Quite unfortunate. I imagine that they just wrote a JNI library to do all the dirty work, so you could semi-easily do the same if you need it enough.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not just after the COMPUTERNAME environment variable, which is what you see in that control panel window?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your reply. The COMPUTERNAME variable returns the Full computer name, a somewhat cryptical string including some seemingly random numbers and characters. What I need is the more readable computer description (windows) / computer name (mac os), as explained above.

Comment: @Mathijs: that name is not usually in DNS.

Answer (score 1):

"Pure" Computer Name for MAC:

```
private static String getComputerName() {
            String s = "";
            try {
                Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("scutil --get ComputerName");
                InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
                int b;
                while ( (b = in.read()) >= 0) {
                    s += (char)b;
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return s;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That Computer Description/Name happens to be the hostname of the localhost. you can verify this by checking your terminal prompt, which typically shows `ComputerName:CurrentDirectory User$` corresponding to a default bash prompt `export PS1="\u@\h\w: "`

So using:

```
try { 
     InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

     // Get hostname 
     String hostname = addr.getHostName();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) { }
```

you should be able to get the localhost name as you want. 
I hope this helps.

**ref:**

- http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/
- http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Local.html

`

Comment: How is this different from the answer that I posted?

Comment: besides the little paragraph there is no particular difference... I might have missed it, my bad..

Comment: as you can see in my question, unfortunately this method does not return the name I need.

Comment: @Mathijs: i see.. It seems i have missed not only @Andy's reply but also the details of your question... 
I should really pay more attention to reading.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I found a way to do this myself, but only on Mac OS. The bounty is still open for people that can come up with a way to answer my question on Windows.

Running this app returns `Computer Description: iMac Mattijs`

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.apple.dnssd.*;

/**
 * Example of finding your computer description. Tested on Mac OS 10.6, Java 1.6
 * 
 * Note: make sure you're not compiling with JavaSE-1.6 but with JVM 1.6.0 (MacOS X Default), otherwise access to DNSSD libraries will be restricted.
 * 
 * @author mattijskneppers
 */

public class DescriptionFinder implements BrowseListener, ResolveListener {
    InetAddress local = null;
    HashMap<DNSSDService, String> fileSharingNameMap = new HashMap<DNSSDService, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DescriptionFinder();
    }   

    public DescriptionFinder() {
        try { local = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); } catch (UnknownHostException e) { System.out.println("Error, couldn't resolve local host"); }

        try {
            DNSSD.browse("_afpovertcp._tcp", this);
        } catch (DNSSDException e) {
            System.out.println("DeviceFinder: problem browsing for new file sharing");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void operationFailed(DNSSDService arg0, int arg1) {}

    @Override
    public void serviceResolved(DNSSDService resolver, int flags, int ifIndex, String fullName, String hostName, int port, TXTRecord txtRecord) {
        InetAddress[] addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(hostName);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        InetAddress ip = null;
        for (InetAddress address : addresses) {
            if (!address.isLinkLocalAddress()) {
                ip = address;
                break;
            }
        }

        String fileSharingName = fileSharingNameMap.get(resolver);
        if (fileSharingName != null) {
            if (ip.equals(local)) {
                System.out.println("Computer Description: " + fileSharingName);
            }
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void serviceFound(DNSSDService service, int flags, int ifIndex, String serviceName, String regType, String domain) {
        //System.out.println("found file sharing: " + serviceName + ", domain: " + domain + ", regType: " + regType + ", flags: " + flags);
        try {
            DNSSDService resolver = DNSSD.resolve(flags, ifIndex, serviceName, regType, domain, this);
            fileSharingNameMap.put(resolver, serviceName);
        } catch (DNSSDException e) {
            System.out.println("DeviceFinder: problem resolving new filesharing device");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void serviceLost(DNSSDService service, int flags, int ifIndex, String serviceName, String regType, String domain) {}
}
```

Comment: @Jeremy: you are right. Your solution is absolutely the way to go.